# Jquery select all Input except type hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, exception, select, input

I am selecting all inputs in jquery, like this:

```
$('input').each(function() {
...
});
```

But is it possible to create an exception like saying select all inputs with the exception of input type hidden.

I know that I could select input with the specific types I need but that does not look that good I think

***Edit:*** sorry made the wrong example, I mean something like this:

```
document.forms["product"].getElementsByTagName("input");
```

with the exception of hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this : you can make use of `:not` with `[type="hidden"]`

```js
$(function(){
  $('input:not([type="hidden"])').each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="1">
<input type="radio" value="2">
<input type="hidden" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" value="4">
```

Answer (score 2):

There are various method to use. I would prefer to use:

```
$('input:visible').each();
```

**Notice:** `:visible` **does not select** the `input` with the `type="hidden"`.

Or you may use a little longer method:

```
$('input:not([type="hidden"]').each();
```

Or,

```
$('input').not('[type="hidden"]').each();
```

API References: [visible-selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/), [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

Answer (score 1):

Since your update

> I mean something like this:
>
> ```
> document.forms["product"].getElementsByTagName("input");
> ```
>
> with the exception of hidden

try:

```
document.forms['product'].querySelectorAll('input:not([type="hidden"])')
```

Comment: So I cannot use getElementsByTagName?

Comment: you could, but that does not do *exceptions*. you would then need to go through your results to check the type.

Comment: if you are using jQuery, then go with @BhushanKawadkar answer.

Comment: so querySelectorAll is basically the same as getElementsByTagName?

Comment: in what sense? as a javascript function and not a jQuery one, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method using `:input:hidden` selector to exclude `hidden` elements.

**`.not`** *will remove elements from the set of matched elements*

```
$('input').not(':input:hidden').each(function() {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('input:not[type=hidden]').each(function(){

});
```